# Where can I find "detailed" error analysis of modified Euler's methods?

Tags: numerical-methods, eulers-method, truncation-error

I'm studying the local truncation error of each Heun's, Midpoint, and Ralston's methods. For Heun's method, I found a material in [here](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/%7Eece204a/Laboratories/08/Heuns/). However, I don't get how the following is derived.
$$
f(t+h, y(t+h)) = f(t+t, y(t)+hf(t,y(t)) + \frac 1 2 f_2(\tau_3, y(\tau_3))y^{(2)}(\tau_3)h^2
$$
where
$$
f_2(\tau_3,y(\tau_3)) = \left.\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(\tau_3,y)\right|_{y=y(\tau_3)}
$$
I can understand the $\tau_3$ comes from the mean-value theorem, but I cannot understand the calculus itself.

I also could not find the detailed explanation of error analyses for Midpoint and Ralston's method. Where can I find them? Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just Taylor's formula... First in one variable:
$$
y(t+h) = y(t) + h y'(t) + \frac{h^2}{2}y''(\xi)= y(t) + h f(t,y) + \frac{h^2}{2}y''(\xi_t)
$$

Then is two variables,

\begin{align*}
f(t+h, y(t+h)) = & f\left(t+h, y(t) + h f(t, y(t)) + \frac{h^2}2 h^2y''(\xi_t)\right)\\
=& f\Bigl(t+h, y(t)+hf(t,y(t))\Bigr) + \frac{h^2}{2} y''(\xi_t) f'_y(t,y(\tilde \xi_t))
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh I got it! So, the cited reference is not correct. The tau_3 in both f and y^(2) must be different, right?